Estimates on Holder Norms and $C$^k norms
I'm dealing with some estimates. There are some very useful estimates on Holder norms in a paper by Hormander. But I can't relate them immediately to the usual $C^k$ norms. The estimates appear in Appendix A of this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00251855
The $a$-Holder semi-norm for a smooth function $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $U$ compact, convex and with non-empty interior is defined as
$$
    |f|_a:= \sup_{\substack{x, y \in U \\ x \neq y}} \dfrac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^a}.
$$
Then for $k < a \le k + 1$ he defines
$$
    |f|_a := \sum_{|I| = k} |\partial^If|_{a - k}.
$$
Then he defines the Holder norm
$$
    \|f\|_a:= |f|_a + \sup |f|.
$$
He shows that when we have a bound on $|f|_a$ and $|f|_b$ with $a < b$, then we have a bound on the suprimum norm of all the partial derivatives $\partial^If$ with $I$ = k such that $a\le k < b$. This already suggests that these Holder norms should be very si,ilar to the $C^k$-norms. But for a natural number $k$, the way he defines the $H^{k + a}$ norms requires that $0 < a \le 1$. This makes it quite hard for me to relate them to $C^k$ norms. One would like to think that this is the same as the $H^{(k-1) + 1}$ but I'm not sure if they really are equivalent or not.
In particular, I really need the below estimates (or something similar to them) but for $C^k$ norms
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    \|f.g\|_{H^{k + a}} &\le C (\|f\|_{H^{k + a}} \|g\|_{H^{0}} + \|f\|_{H^{0}}\|g\|_{H^{k + a}})
    \\
    \|f\circ \Phi\|_{H^{k + a}} &\le C(\|f\|_{H^{k + a}}\|\Phi\|_{H^1}^{k + a} + \|f\|_{H^{1}}\|\Phi\|{H^{k + a}} + \|f \circ \Phi\|_{H^{0}})
    \end{aligned}
$$
I would greatly appreciate it if you can help.
